# Is it possible to use variables in seperate css files with sass/compass while still using shared mixins?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am new to sass and compas, and I am trying to optimise my code.  I would like to separate my css files, so I can have page specific css files only included in the pages that require them.

e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/global.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/thispage.css" />
```

My global sass file contains several partials for fonts, buttons etc.  Each of these included partials contain mixins and variable that I want to extend from in my individual page scss files while keeping generated page specific css files seperate.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, not unless you include the files, but that is not what your doing

Comment: Whatever files you `@import` you will have access to the variable's and `@mixins` inside

Comment: Also look into compressing your CSS. By separating CSS into page-specific files, you lose the benefit of caching the CSS from the 1st page. Although with a big enough filesize, separating them would be the better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include variables in your `.css` files. You can just do that in your `.scss` or `.sass` files. And you have to `@import` the file that has the variables into the file  you want to use them.

For example, in your **general.scss** you have:

```
$blue = #00FFFF;
```

And you need use it in another file, you need to import that file:

```
@import 'general';

a {
  color: $blue;
}
```